# Error while trying to retrive the username in an iFrame facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, serverfbml

I am developing a facebook application with iFrame render method. So in order to display my name, I used serverfbml tags. This is my code:

```
 <fb:serverfbml style="width: 760px;"> 

     <script type="text/fbml"> 

     <fb:fbml> 

      <fb:name uid='$user_id' useyou='false'></fb:name>

      </fb:fbml>

     </script>

 </fb:serverfbml>
```

But The output is " Facebook User". 
Please explain me why I get this kind of output.

I did an echo of my $user_id, and it displays the id.

Comment: The right way of coding that piece of FBML code is:
`<fb:name uid='<?php echo $user_id;?>' useyou='false'></fb:name>`
Only then the user id gets stored in uid and the corresponding name is displayed. Thanks to Peter Forss, I was able to understand that the app was not able to see the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specification](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/name)  the default text to display if you can't see the user is *Facebook User*.

You can specify another text to display with the *ifcantsee* property like this:

```
<fb:name uid='$user_id' useyou='false' ifcantsee='Can not see this user'></fb:name>
```

**The [specification](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/name)  says:**

> Alternate text to display if the
>   logged in user cannot access the user
>   specified. To specify an empty string
>   instead of the default, use
>   ifcantsee="". Default value is
>   Facebook User

Comment: Ok,now I get, Can not see this user.Do I have to set any permissions?  But I'm working from my id and trying to display my name. The User Id is diplayed properly.

Comment: Now I tried giving in my User Id Directly to the <fb:name>  code, and now I get my name displayed..